# How to implement Codeigniter's set_value() function in smarty when repopulating a form?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

Works like that in plain HTML, but I've failed to implement in smarty, and I didn't find a good solution.

```
<input type="text" name="{$field_name}" value="{$value|default:0}" class="form-control">
```

The line I need to implement to, looks like above.

Comment: because `set_value` is function of codeigniter.

Comment: @Devsi So there's no option to implement it to smarty like I do in blade when using Laravel's old() ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to solve the problem, so I made a frontend validation also in Jquery.

```
('#save_form_btn').on('click', function (e) {
 if(/*condition*/){
$('#value_id + small').remove();
$('#value_id').addClass('is-invalid');
$('#value_id').after('<small class="text-danger">{"error message"}</small>');              
e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Note the followings:

1. I have backend validation also (Codeigniter's form validation)
2. This code prevents form submit if value is not as expected, so you
   don't need to get old data (If user don't pass frontend validation,
   backend validation won't be triggered)
3. This isn't an answer for the original question, but gives a
   workaround which can help some maybe.
4. JQuery is not my cup of coffee, so feel free to improve as needed.